# Почта попадает в спам, как изменить?

Tags: php, email

Добавил обычную функцию отправки письма:

```
<?php
$to = "web-ba89f@mail-tester.com"; 

$subject = "Test mail"; 

$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message."; 

$from = "registration@MYDOMAIN.RU"; 

$headers = "From: Info <registration@MYDOMAIN.RU>\r\n"; 

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 

echo "Mail Sent.";
```

Решил проверить на спам через mail-tester. Он показывает 0/10(даже -2).
Самая основная Ошибка, это: Адрес возврата : webmaster@example.com. Хотя я установил FROM. Ошибка точно не в коде отправки почты.
И так же пишет [SPF] example.com не позволяет Вашему серверу myserverIP использовать webmaster@example.com
Те же самые ошибки наблюдаю, если отправляю на любой почтовый сервер письмо. Например на mail.ru. Потом захожу в сведения письма и вижу снова несовпадения. Как будто я отправляю почту от имени другого домена. Хотя я зарегистрировал адрес почты.

Как еще подтвердить, что мой сервер, домен и почта одно целое?

Установлен centos на vds. Стоит ispManager.
Настроил на домене все необходимые txt, CNAME, mx записи с yandex
Добавил через pdd.yandex.ru домен и подтвердил его. Создал там почту. Добавил все необходимые spf, DKIM подписи

**РЕШЕНИЕ**
Необходимо установить опцию sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f mail@domain.com
в php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISPManager использует для PHP тот E-Mail, который прописан для сайта в его настройках в качестве адреса вебмастера. Это делается путём установки параметра PHP `sendmail_path` в конфигурационных файлах Apache, добавляя в секцию `<IfModule php5_module>` строку вида `php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@example.com"`. Можете попробовать сменить в панели адрес на ваш настоящий. Этот параметр относится к PHP_INI_SYSTEM, так что изменить его можно лишь в системном php.ini или в конфигурационном файле Apache. Также не забудьте про SPF, DKIM и DMARC записи в DNS.

Answer (score -1):

В первую очередь вам нужно использовать `PhpMailer` А во вторых вы должны использовать серфецированые `SMTP` Сервера, вроде `Gmail`.